# how to display multi-dimensional data from collection in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

how to show multidimensional data from collection. say i have this

```
links.insert({
cat:[{
    name:'js',
    sub:[{
        name:'angularJS',
        links:[{
            url:'something.com'},{url:'another.com'}]
        },{
        name:'meteorJS',
        links:[{
            url:'something.com'},{url:'another.com'}]
        }]
    }]
});
```

retrieving the data in helper like this

```
'links':function(){
    return links.find();  // also tried links.find().fetch()
```

one option is that to use separate helpers for specific data. but i want to use single helper which will receive the whole data and show it like

```
{{‪#‎each‬ links}}
    {{cat.name}} : {{sub.name}} : {{links.url}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: `sub` and `links` are arrays, do you what to show only the first one or loop through all of them?

Comment: i want to loop through all of them

Comment: Can you fix your indentation? looks like `name:'meteorJS'` is inside the links array, is it missing a `{` before it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
{{#each link}}
    {{cat.[0].name}}  :  {{cat.[0].sub.[0].name}}  :  {{cat.[0].sub.[0].links.[0].url}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It's probably `{{name}}` instead of `{{cat.name}}` since cat would be `this` inside the loop.

Comment: Oh, yeah didn't notice the array on cat. it should be cat.[0].name and so forth.. updated now. But as you might have noticed it will only print the first item on all lists.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON isn't valid. Your helper would look like this:

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
      link: function () {
          var cat = [
                        {
                            "name": "meteorJS",
                            "sub": [
                                {
                                    "name": "angularJS",
                                    "links": [
                                        {
                                            "url": "something.com"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "url": "another.com"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "angularJS",
                                    "links": [
                                        {
                                            "url": "something.com"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "url": "another.com"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "links": []
                        }
                    ];
        return cat;
      }
    });
```

The Template would look like this:

```
<template name="yourTemplate">
    {{#each link}}
        {{name}}  :  {{sub.[0].name}}  :  {{sub.[0].links.[0].url}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: why is json is invalid? i'm retrieving data from collection,not declaring it in helper

Comment: your solution work for hard code data ,but i'm saving data into a collection and want retrieve and show data from that collection

Comment: It's the same solution. Then cat = YourCollection.find().fetch();

Answer (score 0):

When you have to loop over the elements, you should use `{{#each foo}}`, where `foo` is the context used inside the each.

```
{{#each link}}
    {{ name }} :
    {{#each sub}}
        {{ name }} :
        {{#each links}}
            {{ url }}
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Notice it is calling `{{ name }}` and not `{{ cat.name }}`, same for the next name and for url.